# Can't access into any .wordpress.com websites

Tags: 14.04, networking, browser, websites

Few days ago I've taken broadband connection. I set up the DSL cable connection from network manager and using the username and password I could perfectly connect to the internet. But I found that I can't access into any .wordpress.com blogs and some other websites. It shows just loading but the webpage doesn't appear.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here is the output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:1a:06:e9:69:c8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::221a:6ff:fee9:69c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:56506 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:53712544 (53.7 MB)  TX bytes:9554010 (9.5 MB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1543246 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:1543246 (1.5 MB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:192.168.73.160  P-t-P:192.168.73.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::c838:8a30:c7d4:f54/10 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:59392 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:51344545 (51.3 MB)  TX bytes:8071683 (8.0 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:d2:1e:a4:55:93  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:91 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:15221 (15.2 KB)
```

output of `ping` command for another inaccessible website:

```
ping www.rokomari.com
PING www.rokomari.com (184.73.108.203) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- www.rokomari.com ping statistics ---
294 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 292999ms
```

output of `ping -c 4 wordpress.com`

```
PING wordpress.com (192.0.78.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.0.78.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=72.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.17: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=72.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.17: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=72.7 ms
64 bytes from 192.0.78.17: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=71.5 ms

--- wordpress.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 71.526/72.142/72.707/0.545 ms
```

Output of: `traceroute --max-hops=10 wordpress.com`

```
traceroute to wordpress.com (192.0.78.9), 10 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.73.1 (192.168.73.1)  1.413 ms  1.398 ms  1.388 ms
 2  192.168.98.41 (192.168.98.41)  2.208 ms  2.203 ms  2.197 ms
 3  103.43.150.97 (103.43.150.97)  2.820 ms  2.814 ms  2.802 ms
 4  103.43.148.249 (103.43.148.249)  3.538 ms * *
 5  * * *
 6  * 103.9.136.241 (103.9.136.241)  2.217 ms  2.259 ms
 7  t-0-2-0-core2-dhk.novocom-bd.com (103.9.136.249)  2.250 ms  2.991 ms  3.308 ms
 8  p-0-1-1-core-sg.novocom-bd.com (103.9.138.249)  61.158 ms  61.140 ms  61.114 ms
 9  aes-static-025.1.22.125.airtel.in (125.22.1.25)  71.862 ms  71.858 ms  71.793 ms
10  125.62.187.117 (125.62.187.117)  191.575 ms  191.569 ms  188.738 ms
```

Output of: `wget http://wordpress.com`

```
--2015-02-23 19:57:27--  http://wordpress.com/
Resolving wordpress.com (wordpress.com)... 192.0.78.9, 192.0.78.17
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.com/ [following]
--2015-02-23 19:57:28--  https://wordpress.com/
Connecting to wordpress.com (wordpress.com)|192.0.78.9|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [  <=>                                  ] 17,105      49.4KB/s   in 0.3s   

2015-02-23 19:57:29 (49.4 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [17105]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `ping -c 4 wordpress.com` and `traceroute --max-hops=10 wordpress.com`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: You may need to install `traceroute` for that.

Comment: `traceroute is already the newest version.` @Jos

Comment: To make sure that it isn't a browser issue, try `wget http://wordpress.com` and see if it stores any data (should load 17383 bytes, currently).

Comment: @Jos I've added the output of `wget http://wordpress.com`
Please check it out. It just downloads index.html file only.

Comment: Yep, wget can access the web. So you have a browser issue. Have you specified a proxy server in your browser settings?

Comment: No I didn't specified a proxy server in my browser settings. Here is a screenshot of my Firefox browser settings: http://ctrlv.in/506999 Please check it.

Comment: Just in case, clear out the cache... If nothing helps, then could you install another browser and try from it? (e.g. chromium-browser)

Comment: Hmm, strange. Can't think of anything else. Perhaps browse to `https://192.0.78.9`? Or: close firefox and start with a new blank profile?

Comment: This looks like an issue with your DSL router or ISP perhaps, and not Ubuntu. Can you open these sites through the same router from a different OS or device?

Comment: Yes when I connect my laptop with my modem connection then I can open these sites without any problem using the same browser.

But problems occur when I connect with my broadband connection. And can't access only .wordpress.com sites..everything else are okay! 

I cant figure out where is the actual problem. :/ @dobey